# Getting error UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, group membership operation already in progress: []

Tags: apex

I am trying to merge the contact & getting the below error:

> System.DmlException: Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   003c000000FuDcKAAQ; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, group membership
>   operation already in progress: []

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Feels like there is some trigger at backend which is invoked on update or delete for contact .Check your debug logs to figure the root cause

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, yes, there is trigger which calls after delete of contact. But any idea when & why this issue occurs?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I think, It is known issue in salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Salesforce uses a central Group object to manage visibility related to the Role Hierarchy, Territory Hierarchy, Public Groups and Queues.

When administrative changes occur in these areas a group membership lock is taken to ensure data integrity is maintained while complex sharing calculations are completed.

The following activities take out group membership locks for the duration of their transaction:

- Role creation
- Role deletion
- Moving a role in the hierarchy
- Adding a user to a territory
- Removing a user from a territory
- Moving a territory in the hierarchy
- Territory deletion
- Territory creation
- Provisioning an internal user with an existing role
- User role change
- Provisioning a non-HVPU portal user under an account
- Portal Account owner change
- User Role change of a user who owns one or more portal accounts

Here is a detailed [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/09/%E2%80%9Cgroup-membership-operation-already-in-progress%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%93-managing-group-membership-locks-for-success.html)